# What special role plays the function $\pi^{\frac x\pi}$ in analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, zeta-functions, functional-equations

I have tried to redefine some special functions in the most "natural" way, that is the way which allows to simplify the relations the most. I would call these functions "parelementary". The definitions are as follows:

$$\operatorname{pg }\,\,x =\frac 1\pi \psi\left(\frac x\pi\right)$$

$$\operatorname{cpg }\,\,x=-\frac 1\pi \psi\left(1-\frac x\pi\right)=-\operatorname{pg }(\pi-x)$$

$$\operatorname{gn}\,\,x=\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac x \pi \right)$$

$$\operatorname{lgn}\,\,x=\ln \left|\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac x\pi\right)\right|=\ln|\operatorname{gn}(x)|$$

$$\operatorname{zn}\,\,x=\frac {2x}\pi\left(\frac {2x}\pi-1\right)\zeta\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)$$

$$\operatorname{expi}\,\,x=\pi^{\frac{x}\pi}$$

$$\operatorname{czn}\,\,x=\frac {2x}\pi\left(\frac {2x}\pi-1\right)\zeta\left(1-\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)\pi^{\frac{2x}\pi}=\operatorname{zn}\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\operatorname{expi}(2x)$$

Here is a graphic of pg (orange), cpg (blue), gn (green), zn (red), czn (violet).
[image]
They exhibit the following relations:
$$\operatorname{pg}\,\, x + \operatorname{cpg}\,\, x = - \cot x$$

$$\operatorname{pg}\,\, (-x) + \operatorname{cpg}\,\, x = \frac 1x$$

$$\operatorname{gn}\,\, x\operatorname{gn}(\pi-x)=\csc x$$

$$(\operatorname{gn}\,\, x)'=\operatorname{gn}\,\, x\, \operatorname{pg}\,\, x $$

$$(\operatorname{lgn}\,\, x)'=\operatorname{pg}\,\, x$$

But also there are relations which involve expi:

$$\operatorname{zn}\left(x + \frac \pi4\right) \operatorname{expi}(-x) \operatorname{gn}\left(x + \frac \pi4\right)=\operatorname{zn}\left(-x + \frac \pi4\right) \operatorname{expi}(x) \operatorname{gn}\left(-x + \frac \pi4\right)$$

$$\operatorname{czn}\left(-x + \frac \pi4\right) \operatorname{expi}\left(x-\frac\pi2\right) \operatorname{gn}\left(x + \frac \pi4\right)=\operatorname{czn}\left(x + \frac \pi4\right) \operatorname{expi}\left(-x-\frac\pi2\right) \operatorname{gn}\left(-x + \frac \pi4\right)$$

$$D^{s/\pi}[\operatorname{cpg }\,\,x]|_{x=0}=\operatorname{expi}\left(\frac\pi2-s\right)\operatorname{gn}\, s\operatorname{zn} \frac s2$$

Thus I wonder what is the special role of exponential function with base $\pi^{1/\pi}$.

- Can the above functions be re-defined such a way so to get rid of the exponent while keeping the relations, thus simplifying them?
- Can the above functions be re-defined so to replace the exponent with base $\pi^{1/\pi}$ with exponent with base $e$ everywhere but still keeping the identities?
- Does exponent with base $\pi^{1/\pi}$ exhibit any duality with exponent with base $e$?
- Does exponent with base $\pi^{1/\pi}$ satisfy any simple and unique differential or functional equation?

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: What do you mean by "duality" between exponentials with different bases? The graph of one is an affine transformation (here, scaling the $x$ axis) of the other. You appear to be trying to hide the constants occuring in the relations between the special functions, by using these affine tranformations. But as you've noticed this just makes them reappear (with interest!) elsewhere. And you are losing, e.g., the $\Gamma$ function's relation with integer factorial, the relationship of $\exp$ with its own derivative, etc. (I presume $\psi$ is the digamma function, $\Gamma'(x) / \Gamma(x)$?)